# How to speed up random access operation on disk for big hash tables

Tags: performance, algorithm, hash

I need to store 15Gb or records, a record has a fixed size equal to 270 bytes and i want to have ability to find the recor by key. key is the hash of few fields in record, several records can have the same key.
I tried to use gdbm but it's to slow, now i am trying to make my own solution.
I have two main ideas.
1-direct addressing. I create a big file of empty records. the ammount or empty records is twice bigger than i want to store, according this probability that index of new record (new_key%(total record in file)) is index of empty record at least equal to 1/2, If record with this index already busy the next index=hash(key)%total record in file and so far.
This approach gives me good speed of find operation. On the average I need 1.65 read record operation to find appropriate.
But it's very slow to initially fill this file because of a lot of random access operations. It can takes 4 hours.
2 - binary search. just performing parallel merge sort to create file.
But binary search takes 12 times more random read operations with random access to find appropriate record.
My applications very sensitive to speed of find operations but i need to speed up proccess of creatiing this file. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Try `next_index = previous_index + 1`. This converts 1/3 of your random accesses to sequential, hopefully giving some 25% speedup. And unless the hash function is bad, this shouldn't give any more collisions.

Comment: The strongly non-uniform access time of mechanical mass storage orders of magnitude beyond even a process switch is the very reason there are different methods to access data by key that doesn't fit into RAM, [B*-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), for one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have, e.g., 1 GB of available RAM, divide the hash table into 15 pieces and partition the data by which piece of the hash table it belongs in. Then build each piece in RAM and write it out.

Comment: This means reading all the input 15 times though. Also, one has to be very careful about elements jumping from one 1 GB chunk to another due to collisions; if this is not handled correctly, bugs cause by this will be extremely confusing later.

Comment: "This means reading all the input 15 times though." No, there are better algorithms. "Also, one has to be very careful about elements jumping" I think you're overstating the difficulty here.